# is it possible make a blender render pipeline (server)

Tags: import

I’m a Web 3.0 developer specialized in NFT.

I’m trying to make a rendering pipeline that enables these processes automatically.

1. webapp make an image and download(or transfer to) in Blender
2. Import that image to a pre-modeled project
3. render with animation
4. get file to MP4(+ rendering completion notification)

And I’d also like to ask if there is any solution implementing this pipeline by blender itself or using cloud.

thx!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Web 3.0 or making something with clouds, but...

It's possible to prerender an animation with UV render pass and then map an image to that render using compositing in Blender(See: [Map UV Node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/distort/map_uv.html#map-uv-node)). If you make a file ready for this compositing, it is possible to [render from the command line](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/render.html) so you can trigger rendering from another script on your server. You can also change an external image file that Blender uses by simply overwriting it.

Comment: thanks a lot! i will try!